# angular array to repeat nesting the model Invalid?

Tags: angularjs

I try to repeat a multilayer array in angular,but may be using the method is not correct, this is the example:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("index", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
  $scope.list = [
    {
      list2: ["1111"]
    },
    {
      list2: ["2222"]
    },
    {
      list2: ["3333"]
    }
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="index">
  <ul ng-repeat="l in list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in l.list2">
      <input type="text" ng-model="item" style="width: 300px;"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
<pre>{{list |json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I think proble in json, you have given json same name at all variable list2 .

Comment: I cannot see any problem. The example seems to make exactly what you are looking for: ng-repeat in two levels. Maybe you need to be more specific about the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

What You are using is also correct.
You can simplify it using following implementation.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("index", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
  $scope.list = [
    ["1111"],["2222"],["3333"]
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="index">
  <ul ng-repeat="l in list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in l">
      <input type="text" ng-model="item" style="width: 300px;"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
<pre>{{list |json}}</pre>
</div>
```